# Round background of numbering

Tags: html, list, css

I have a list, where every number is styled. What you should focus on is the background of the number. Right now it will take the shape of the number. How to make this background more circular, ideally a nice smooth circle? Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/cmfL2643/37/).

CSS:

```
.rounded-list a:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: relative;
    left: -1em;
    top: 64%;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    background: rgba(255, 168, 76, 0.5);
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: .3em solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudo element is, by default, an inline-element, which you cannot set the width or height of. Change the display to `inline-block`:

```
.rounded-list a:before {
    display:inline-block;
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: relative;
    left: -1em;
    top: 64%;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    background: rgba(255, 168, 76, 0.5);
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: .3em solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kvhap9/)**
Note that in the jsfiddle, adding the height and width to the element causes the text to flow to a second line. I changed the `.rounded-list a` width to 150px to fix this.

Comment: Jacob thanks. That created a circle. However, it will make the text change line, instead of keeping all the text of the `li` in the same line. Didn't you get that result when running the fiddle? I need the text not to change line.

Comment: @gsamaras Lol, I have no objections to that :P Glad I could help :)